# How can I start activity with android material design animation on android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to create a custom android animation so when I'll leave an activity the new activity will expand from the button clicked kind of like this

[image: example]

Only I want the new activity to expand from the button clicked.
Is there a way of doing this on a non 'android L' device?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way, and It looks super slick.

It basically involves 4 steps:
1. Make 2nd activity transparent
2. Measure the size and position of the view you want to animate in the 1st activity and pass it to the 2nd activity in a bundle
3. animate the layout change in the 2nd activity using the onPreDraw lister and data from 1st activity.
4. Overwrite the default Activity transitions

check out this [DevByte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA), It explains exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check ActivityOptionsCompat class. You can use it like this:

```
final ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeScaleUpAnimation(yourButton, 0, 0, 0, 0);
startActivity(activityStartingIntent, options.toBundle());
```

This should create transition starting from the specified view and given initial size (which is 0 in this example).

Comment: how to end started activity with the scaledown transition?